# Which engines do major browsers use?

Tags: browser

What engines do these browsers use:

- Firefox; is it Gecko?
- Safari; is it Webkit?
- Chrome
- Internet Explorer

Comment: Is he talking about the Rendering Engine or the Javascript Engine?

Comment: Has he ever heard of google? I found the answer to each one of these using the I'm feelin lucky button + Web browser title + engine.

Comment: Wikipedia lists them all. And most people mean the rendering engine if they aren't specific.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- Firefox and other Mozilla browsers (IceWeasel, etc) use **Gecko**.
- Internet Explorer uses **Trident**.
- Safari, Google Chrome and Konqueror use **Webkit**, although on 04/03/2013 Google announced that Chrome will use its own fork from Webkit named **Blink**
- Opera 9+ uses **Presto**, although [it has announced (4/2013)](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/04/04/opera-confirms-it-will-follow-google-and-ditch-webkit-for-blink-as-part-of-its-commitment-to-chromium/) that is will move over to using **Blink**.

Comment: Has konqueror actually switched to webkit, last I checked it was still KHTML (which of course webkit was a fork of).

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure.  For general programming that doesn't deal with engine specifics, I find that considering it to be a Webkit engine works fine.

Comment: Well, there are differences but the KHTML and Webkit devs often submit to each others code repositories.

Comment: Especially now KHTML has native builds cross platform too now (since QT went opensource on windows).

Comment: thanks...now that I think about it, I should of just searched on Google...(smacking self on head)

Comment: I just searched google and found this entry.  How convenient. ;) +1

Comment: Firefox Focus on Android uses Webkit.

mozilla/5.0 (linux; android 8.0.0) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) version/4.0 focus/2.5 chrome/62.0.3202.84 mobile safari/537.36