# Which browsers support WebKit CSS?

Tags: css, webkit

Which browsers support WebKit CSS, like *-webkit-border-radius*,
etc. (other than [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29))? [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6)? [Internet Explorer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7)? [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wikipedia has a summary of [what browsers use WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based) as their HTML rendering engine. The WebKit Project itself has even an [more complete list](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Applications%20using%20WebKit).

Comment: this list is missing info about browsers (not based on webkit) but support many -webkit prefixed for compatibility reasons... see my answer (2021)

Answer (score 8):

**Year 2021:** Google Chrome, Safari, Opera natively support WebKit, but nowadays also Firefox and Microsoft Edge support *-webkit-* prefixed CSS for compatibility reasons. Only Internet Explorer does not.

Comment: Good answer, +1.  For web apps made to be used commercially on one of these platforms, is there any reason to hesitate about using WebKit then?

Comment: I prefer to check for every -webkit- prefixed CSS property used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at the engines the most popular browsers use, as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182885/which-engines-do-firefox-safari-chrome-use):

> - Firefox and other Mozilla browsers (IceWeasel, etc.) use [Gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software)).
> - Internet Explorer uses [Trident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(software)).
> - Safari, Google Chrome and [Konqueror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror) use [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit).
> - Opera 9+ uses [Presto](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20Presto).

So no, neither Internet Explorer, nor Firefox or Opera supports the WebKit CSS styles (although of course Firefox have their [own extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions) which are similar).

Any browsers using WebKit should support the CSS `webkit` prefixed CSS styles.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Konqueror still uses their original KHTML engine. No idea if that information is out of date. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror#Web_browser

Comment: OUTDATED answer!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not being sarcastic here, but most likely any web browser based on WebKit. Aside from Safari, there is Google's Chrome that is based on WebKit, so they would probably support these too.

Comment: And FYI, IE browsers are not based on webkit so they are definitely out.

Answer (score 2):

[Shiira](http://shiira.jp/en.php), browsers on Symbian [S60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29) phones, Safari, and Google Chrome are WebKit browsers.