# How to detect the browser is webkit supported browser?

Tags: webkit

How to check if the browser i work is support webkit via code (javascript or jquery or html)?

Comment: this question asked before may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306269/webkit-css-support-which-browsers

Answer (score -1):

```
var isWebkit = (window.webkitURL != null);

if(isWebkit){
    alert("i am a webkit based browser!");
}
```

Comment: This works in chrome. but not in safari. is safari webkit browser?