# Animate({right: 0}) not working properly in Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, google-chrome, jquery-animate, opera

I try to have an image slide from left to right using only jQuery and it works perfectly with `.animate({right: 0}, 1500)` on Firefox but not on Chrome and Opera (haven't tried other browsers though).

Here is a code example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Slide this squirrel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:relative;margin:1%;padding:1%;border:1px solid black">
            <img id="squirrel" src="squirrel.jpg" alt="What a squirrel..." style="position:absolute;" />
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#squirrel").animate({right: 0}, 5000);
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `100%` to the `right` property for `#squirrel` in the `CSS` file.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="position:relative;margin:1%;padding:1%;border:1px solid black">
     <img id="squirrel" src="http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/imagecache/middle/squirrel_2_line_art.png" height="80" width="100" style="position:absolute;" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#squirrel").animate({right: 0}, 5000);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#squirrel{
    right:100%;
}
```

I created an `JSFiddle` for you.

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/m99bybnp/

**EDIT:**

I made a small change in the `JS` file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // We calculate the width which we need for the wanted displacement
    var width_Animate = $('#container_Squirrel').width() - $('#squirrel').width() ;
    $("#squirrel").animate({left: width_Animate}, 5000);
});
```

New JSFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/m99bybnp/2/

Comment: Thank you, it fixes the animation problem but now the utmost left side of squirrel image is not aligned with the utmost left side of the container (minus the padding of course) inside of the div. Instead, the squirrel is hidden because too much on the right...

Comment: Great the second fiddle works like a charm! Any idea why Chrome and Opera behave like this and not Firefox? Is it a Webkit / Gecko difference? (Could you please add the changes in your answer so that I can accept it?)

Comment: @IamZesh Each browser interprets the HTML of a particular form. See this link, is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1182888/4359029