# Uploading image in ipad is too slow

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ipad

I'm trying to upload an image from my ipad camera but it takes 15 - 20 seconds to be uploaded, But in my personal computer it takes 1 - 2 seconds for the same picture to load,

here is my code:

```html
<input id="idrightSide" style="display: none;" name="file" multiple="true" type="file" label="Select File aaa" id="uploader" onchange='angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this.files, "rightSide")' accept="image/*" />
<img ng-src="/imagesXp/{{image}}" />
```

Comment: You have provided very little information. Have you tried different browsers on iPad by the way?

Comment: @sisyphus I believe there's only one browser on iOS and it is called *Safari* (UIWebView and WKWebView).

Comment: Well, your belief is wrong. You can install multiple browsers on your iPad from your Apple App Store. An example would be [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1) .

Comment: Have you looked at the speed of the internet your iPad has? I could imagine this could be slower for wifi compared to a computer which is plugged in..

Comment: @sisyphus But all browsers have to use the Safari engine, so ...

Comment: @zeroflagL Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1182888/3690942) But that's not the point. I wanted the user to test if he is facing the issue across browsers or if it is limited to just one.

Comment: @sisyphus The reference is about the desktop versions. And yes, that somewhat is the point.

Comment: @zeroflagL Well then you have a point [there](http://www.howtogeek.com/184283/why-third-party-browsers-will-always-be-inferior-to-safari-on-iphone-and-ipad/) And no use testing across multiple browsers.